# Adding arm64 multiarch causes error on fresh Ubuntu 18.04 image

Tags: update-manager, multiarch, arm64

Here is how to reproduce the issue:

```
docker run -it ubuntu:18.04 bash

apt-get update
dpkg --add-architecture arm64
apt-get update
```

The output of the final `apt-get update` is many lines of not found errors:

```
root@4b078bedbe38:/# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease        
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted arm64 Packages  
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages       
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages   
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse arm64 Packages 
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Err:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main arm64 Packages
Err:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Err:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main arm64 Packages
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@4b078bedbe38:/#
```

Why is this occurring? How do I resolve these?
I would expect this to work on a fresh image...

**EDIT**
Another strange thing is the following. On my own machine, if I run `sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev:arm64` I get `libopenblas-dev:arm64 is already the newest version`, meaning the package can be found.

However, running the command `apt-get install libopenblas-dev:arm64` in the docker image returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libopenblas-dev:arm64
```

Not sure why the package is found on my machine (also running Ubuntu 18.04), but can't be found in the image.

Answer (score 1):

Those repositories are only of `i386` and `amd64` architectures. Check for yourself (`dists/focal/` directory) in: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

Add `arm64` repositories which are in http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/